Error: npm is not found when compile Apache Doris release-2.0.3
I am trying to compile Apache Doris release-2.0.3 in macOS 13.3.1 with M1 chip, after I installed all dependencies followed by the official document https://doris.apache.org/docs/2.0/install/source-install/compilation-mac/, then run build.sh in terminal. run into this issue:
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-LAST-VALUE.md (deflated 44%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/window-function-avg.md (deflated 47%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-MIN.md (deflated 43%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-COUNT.md (deflated 48%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION.md (deflated 53%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-RANK.md (deflated 43%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-DENSE-RANK.md (deflated 45%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/window-function-max.md (deflated 43%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-WINDOW-FUNNEL.md (deflated 49%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-FIRST-VALUE.md (deflated 49%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-LEAD.md (deflated 52%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/WINDOW-FUNCTION-ROW-NUMBER.md (deflated 44%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/window-functions/window-function-ntile.md (deflated 43%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/ (stored 0%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/frontends.md (deflated 57%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode-json-array.md (deflated 82%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/queries.md (deflated 61%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode.md (deflated 52%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/backends.md (deflated 62%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/frontends_disks.md (deflated 52%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode-numbers-outer.md (deflated 40%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode-split.md (deflated 62%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/s3.md (deflated 74%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/hdfs.md (deflated 58%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode-bitmap.md (deflated 67%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/iceberg-meta.md (deflated 59%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/workload-group.md (deflated 51%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/numbers.md (deflated 40%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/catalogs.md (deflated 70%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/local.md (deflated 53%)
  adding: contents/sql-functions/table-functions/explode-numbers.md (deflated 38%)
node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
Error: npm is not found

What should I do to fix this issue? I already tried to unset the NODE_OPTIONS like this:
unset NODE_OPTIONS

It still did not fixed this issue. This is the npm version output in terminal:
➜  doris git:(release-2.0.3) ✗ npm -v
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
9.6.7

I have tried to export path like this:
export PATH=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npm:$PATH

